# memcmp with arrays of arrays

Tags: c, strcmp, memcmp

In C, I want to check a given array of chars for an arbitrary letter, and change it according to what it is. For example, the characters "a" or "A" would be changed to "4"(the character representing 4). This is a coding excercise for me :)

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <zlib.h>

#define NUM_BUFFERS 8
#define BUFFER_LENGTH 1024

char buffArrays[NUM_BUFFERS][BUFFER_LENGTH];

int main(int argc, const char* arg[v])
{
    const char a[] = "a";

    gzFile file;
    file = gzopen("a.txt", "rb"); //contains 8 lines of 1024 'a's
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < NUM_BUFFERS)
    {
        gzread(file, buffArrays[counter], BUFFER_LENGTH - 1);
        counter++;
    }
    counter = 0;
    while(counter < NUM_BUFFERS)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for( i; i < BUFFER_LENGTH; i++ )
        {
            int *changed = &buffArrays[counter][i];
            if( memcmp(&a, changed, 1) == 0 )
                printf("SUCCESS\n");
        }
        counter++;
    }
    gzclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

This code never reaches the "SUCCESS" part. This says to me that either

(1) the value of changed is not pointing to the correct thing
(2) the pointer &a is incorrect
(3) I am completely wrong and it is something else

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wish I could click answer for all of you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

The following assigns the value `0x61` or `'a'` to the character string.

```
const char a[] = 'a';
```

You probably rather meant to write

```
const char a = 'a'; /* assign a character to a character */
```

or

```
const char a[] = "a"; /* assign a string to a string */
```

The next thing is with the following statement. Hereby you assign a pointer to an `int` with the memory address of a `char`. Which invokes undefined behavior as you are reading over the bounds of your valid memory in the next statement.

```
int *changed = &bufferArrays[counter][i];
```

Hereby you compare the first four bytes starting from both addresses. Both variables are only one byte wide.

```
if( memcmp(&a, changed, 4) == 0 )
```

If you only want to know whether there is an 'a' in some of your buffer, why don't you just.

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < NUM_BUFFERS; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < BUFFER_LENGTH; j++)
    if (bufferArrays[i][j] == 'a') printf("got it!\n");
```

Comment: so it should be `char *changed = &bufferArrays[counter][i];`?

Comment: also `if( memcmp(&a, changed, 1) == 0)` ?

Comment: mostly because the actual next step involves changing what is currently at the address held by changed

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
bufferArrays[counter] = "a";
```

is not legal. It assigns a pointer to a single `char` and should give a compiler error (or at least a warning). Instead try

```
bufferArrays[counter] = 'a';
```

<strike>Also, in the `while` loops (both of them) you do not increase `counter` and so loop over the same index over and over forever.</strike>

**Edit:** Further problems

The condition where you do the comparison is flawed as well:

```
memcmp(&a, changed, 4)
```

The above doesn't compare pointers, it compares the *contents* of what the pointers point to, and you compare four bytes while the contents is only a single byte. Besides, you can't compare the pointers, as they *will* be different; The contents of the variable `a` is stored at a different location than that of the contents of `bufferArrays[counter][i]`.

Comment: I have edited my code to make it clearer. this is not my code verbatim

Comment: @SamP Well then disregard the part about the loops, but my first part is still valid.

Comment: @SamP What you want to do may be possible (although I'm not certain as to what you try to accomplish) but the implementation is definitly flawed. I edited my answer with another problem.

Comment: okay, I guess I do want to compare the contents of the variable a; changed to compare 1 byte

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
bufferArrays[counter] = "a"; //all the buffers contain one "a"
```

is wrong, since `bufferArrays[counter]` is not a character pointer but a character array. You need:

```
strcpy(bufferArrays[counter], "a");
```

Also, you don't show `readTOmodify`, so that part is a bit hard to understand.

Further, strings are best compared with `strcpy()`, which compares character-by-character and stops at the terminating `'\0'`. You use `memcmp()`, and I don't understand the reason for the `4` which is the number of bytes you're comparing.

Comment: I was unsure how many bytes I need to compare to check a POSIX standard char. I put 4 just in case. check new edits

Comment: Also, I'm looking for commentary on my pointering rather than this. It is not my code verbatim, not even the length of the buffers is the same.

Answer (score 1):

1)     bufferArrays[counter] = "a"; //all the buffers contain one "a"

This is not ok, you have to use `strcpy` to copy strings:

```
strcpy(bufferArrays[counter],"a"); //all the buffers contain one "a"
```

2)

```
#define BUFFER_LENGTH 1
```

Here's a problem. Buffer length should be at least 2 if you want to store just one char (for the extra null-termination).

3) In both of your loops, you never change `counter`, which leads to infinite loop.

Where's your code? I don't see any function surrounding it.

**EDIT:**
To assign you can also use:

```
while(counter < NUM_BUFFERS)
{
    bufferArrays[counter][0] = 'a'; //all the buffers contain one "a"
    counter++;
}
```

In any case, you have to have Buffer length as 2 if you want use it as a C-string.

Comment: changed function. This is not my code verbatim, but just a snippet.

Comment: @SamP Still the `BUFFER_LENGTH` and `strcpy` issues are there.

Comment: can I use bufferArrays[counter] = 'a'; ? In my real code it is being read in by gzread from the libz library, but I didn't want any commentary on that but it looks like I've just caused confusion.

Comment: No, because `bufferArrays` is a 2D array. If you just want to copy one char then you can use: `bufferArrays[counter][0]='a';` and loop through.

Comment: You still compare 4 bytes and there's no function...Can you post a compiling code even if it's not working as expected.